# $Q$-value (nuclear)

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I'm studying principles of physics.
I have a question.
In my book, they seem to have calculated the Q value in different ways.
$$
\begin{align}
\rm p + {^{27}_{13}Al} &\rightarrow \rm{^{27}_{14}Si} + n
\\
\rm ^{13}_7N &\rightarrow \rm{^{13}_6C} + e^+ + \nu
\end{align}$$
In first example, they calculate Q = (26.981539 + 1.008665 - 26.986705 - 1.007825)*931.494MeV

In second example, they calculate Q = (13.005739 - 13.003355 - 2x0.000549)*931.494MeV.
All seven elements are atomic masses

In first example, they ignored the energy of an electron by one difference between 13 and 14.
But in second example, they calculated the energy of an electron by one difference between 6 and 7.

Was it their mistake or did I get it wrong?

Comment: No, this is just you not knowing the conventional definition of nuclear masses includes the masses of electrons that goes with them. Every textbook covering the topic writes an example showing exactly how this works. In your first example, the silicon comes with 14 electrons, and there are no electrons with the neutron. The aluminium has 13 electrons but the proton in Hydrogen atom also carries one, so that the masses of electrons cancel exactly. In the 2nd example, carbon only has 6 electrons, whereas the nitrogen has 7. So, positron and electron make up 2 electron masses.

Comment: Thanks. I only thought core. But this is wrong.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/695775/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/229235/44126. Count the "spectator" electrons in the initial state (keeping in mind that a photon beam is a different creature from an atomic hydrogen beam). From the perspective of the nuclear decay, the ion chemistry is usually irrelevant, so we tend to forget to mark ions in the final states.

Answer (score -2):

*** Does this answer deserve two downvotes? ***

Define your formulas as (a+b-c-d)*w

If any of a, b, c or d represents the mass of a reaction product containing protons, as in an isotope, a proton or an alpha particle, the correct mass to be used is the mass that includes the masses of as many electrons as there are protons in the product including the electron-nucleus binding energy, i.e. the correct mass to be used is the mass for the un-ionized atom. For example if a reaction product is the proton, the mass of the unionized hydrogen atom should be used; if the product is the $\alpha$ particle, the mass of the un-ionized $^4He$ atom should be used.

In the first example you have:

(1.00782503223+26.98153853-26.98670469-1.00866491595)*931.49410113274 = -5.594594296324943 MeV

which means there is a threshold of 5.6 MeV for this reaction.

In the second example, you can safely disregard the neutrino's mass as it is going to be negligible, and compute just

(13.00573861-13.00335483507-5.48579909065e-4)*931.49410113274 =

1.7094733364284804 MeV

where 5.48579909065e-4 is the electron's mass in amu.

Find the masses of the natural isotopes at: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Compositions/stand_alone.pl

For $^{13}N$: https://chemlin.org/isotope/nitrogen-13

For $^{27}Si$: https://chemlin.org/isotope/silicon-27

Neutron mass in amu: https://www.physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mnu

Electron mass in amu: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?meu

As for w, compute it with

w = (29979245800^2/(6.02214082e23 * 1.6021766208e-19 * 1.0e7 * 1.0e6)) = (29979245800^2/(6.02214082e23 * 1.6021766208e-6)) = 931.49410113274 MeV/amu

where **29979245800** cm/s is the speed of light, **1.6021766208e-19** C is the electron charge, and **6.02214082e23** is Avogadro's number. The factors 1.0e7 and 1.0e6 are for going from erg to J (CGS to MKS) and from eV to MeV respectively.

Thanks to rob for the correction. I did think that threshold was really a bit high....

Comment: The reaction $\rm {^{27}}Al(p,n){^{27}}Si$ does not have a 1 GeV threshold. You used the mass of Si-28, so you missed a nucleon.